# Oracle WebLogic GroovyServlet Error

Tags: groovy, weblogic

We have a J2EE app running beautifully on tomcat-based app servers, but all groovy scripts seem to fail on weblogic (10.3.5.0) and also IBM WebSphere. It seems the script processing, not the content of the scripts are the issue. The app itsells is a spring MVC web app and the GroovyServlet is part of the web.xml descriptor:

```
<!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Groovlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Groovlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.groovy</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Calling a simple executor.groovy file results in an exception. My test script is small:

```
response.contentType = "application/json"
out.println "test"
```

But fails:

```
GroovyServlet Error:  script: '/executor.groovy':  Script processing failed.null
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Anyone has a solution? Are there general issues with Groovy on weblogic or websphere?

Comment: Do you have more details about the error, or at least the complete stack trace maybe? Check WebLogic logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you're still having this issue :)

I had the same problem - the NullPointerException is caused by ServletContext.getRealPath(...) returning null.

There is a setting in Weblogic admin console which controls whether getRealPath() can be used.
It can also be configured in your weblogic.xml file by inserting the following (not sure how to deal with this in Websphere).

```
<container-descriptor>
    <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
</container-descriptor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `response` or `out` are not properly binded in weblogic. Did you try your servlet on another container. Also publishing more about the stacktrace and the web.xml could help